# Single pair shortest path multiple travelers

Tags: shortest-path

I'm programming a turn based strategy game and I have a special single pair shortest path problem. I have a weighted directed graph with non-negative non-zero edge weights and here is the catch, with multiple travelers, that is units with different movement types traveling together as a group. Each edge of the graph has different weights for different units depending on movement type.

Normally one would use eg. Dijkstras algorithm to solve the shortest path problem. But with multiple units moving together as a group and different edge weights for each unit the case may be that the optimal path is not the same as the optimal path for any single unit moving alone. As can be seen from below

[image: the example picture]

with red and green moving from S to D. The optimal path for red moving alone would be S-A-D with a cost of 2 and the optimal path for green moving alone would be S-C-D with a cost of 2. In both cases, however, the other units movement cost would be 5 and thus the optimal path, with the units moving together, is S-B-D with a maximum movement cost of 4.

Different amounts of movement points per turn per unit type seems not to be a problem since the edge weights could be normalized. Could this be formulated as a linear program and solved with the simplex algorithm ? It would seem we would have multiple objective functions and we would like to minimize the maximum. But is there perhaps a simpler solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the multiple travelers to travel in a group, then you will need to use some sort of an optimization algorithm and find the optimum, like you've suggested.

On the other hand, if you don't need the *optimum* for the whole group (which could take some time), you could try using a heuristic or an approximate optimization algorithm.

Since I don't know the details of your game, I can't say which heuristic could be useful for you. You could, perhaps, minimize the search space a bit by choosing a representative from each of the group (flyer, swimmer, ground unit...), and find the optimum group's path of the selected units.